# Export WiFi points locations from Wigle gets only 100 points

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to export all WiFi points in a city from Wigle. I found a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@neuralnets/building-a-wifi-spots-map-of-networks-around-you-with-wigle-and-python-5adf72a48140) and managed to export only 100 points, but how to export all points? I tried to change the `first` parameter, but that didn't help.

Here's my code:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import folium
import geopandas

# SETTING WiGLE USERNAME & PASSWORD FOR API CALL:
wigle_username = 'i can share it if you need'
wigle_password = 'i can share it if you need'

city = 'Sao Paulo'
# SETTING PARAMETERS:
payload = {'first': '1', 'freenet': 'false', 'paynet': 'false', 'addresscode': city, 'api_key': (wigle_username + wigle_password).encode()}
# FETCHING JSON RESPONSE FROM WiGLE:
details = requests.get(url='https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/geocode', params=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(wigle_username, wigle_password)).json()

# SETTING PARAMETERS:
payload = {'latrange1':'-23.7106507', 'latrange2':'-23.3906507', 'longrange1':'-46.7933824', 'longrange2':'-46.4733824', 'api_key': (wigle_username + wigle_password).encode()}
# FETCHING JSON RESPONSE FROM WiGLE:
results = requests.get(url='https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search', params=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(wigle_username, wigle_password)).json()

# EXTRACTING 'RESULTS' AS A PANDAS DATAFRAME TO WORK WITH:
df = json_normalize(results['results'])
# RENAMING COLUMNS FOR GEOPLOTLIB:
df = df.rename(columns={'trilat': 'lat', 'trilong': 'lon'})
cols = list(df.columns)
# PREVIEWING AVAILABLE INFORMATION:
print(f"Result obtained has {df.shape[0]} rows and {df.shape[1]} columns in it. \n\nThe list of columns include {cols}")

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.lon, df.lat), crs="EPSG:4326"
)

interactive_map1 = folium.Map(
    location=(-23.568399795078903, -46.6474148638533),
    zoom_start=10
)

addresses_layer = folium.features.GeoJson(gdf)
addresses_layer.add_to(interactive_map1)
interactive_map1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please [RTFM](https://api.wigle.net/swagger#/Network%20search%20and%20information%20tools/search_2):

> GET ​/api​/v2​/network​/search  will search the WiGLE Wifi database.
>
> Query the WiGLE database for paginated results based on multiple criteria. API and session authentication default to a page size of 100 results/page. ... Number of daily queries allowed per user are throttled based on history and participation.
>
> To get next page of results put the previous request's `searchAfter` value as a parameter in the new request's `searchAfter`.
> ... Use this instead of 'first'.

If you ignore pagination, your GETs won't retrieve all available entries.

Comment: I don't understand how to use ```searchAfter```. I don't have experience in working with API, so reading the manual does not help much at the moment.

Comment: Say there's 220 result rows. Requesting 1st page will produce 100 of them, along with a helpful `searchAfter=100` or something like that. Include it with your 2nd .get() request, rather than specifying `first`. And again, you'll retrieve 100 rows along with a _new_ helpful `searchAfter`, which you should supply on the 3rd page request to retrieve those leftover twenty rows.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving each response, store the searchAfter provided in the payload:

```
search_after = results['searchAfter']
```

and then use that value in the subsequent request:

```
payload = {'latrange1':'-23.7106507', 'latrange2':'-23.3906507', 'longrange1':'-46.7933824', 'longrange2':'-46.4733824', 'searchAfter': search_after} # note: you shouldn't put your credentials in the payload
```

the first response will also contain a value that will tell you the total number of results for the quad so you can determine how many iterations are necessary:

```
target_iterations = results['totalResults']/100
```

note that if the target results exceed your daily threshold, you'll need to wait until the next calendar day to continue - be sure to test for `response.status_code == 429` and break accordingly, preserving your `searchAfter`